# Remove seconds from timepicker in web2py?

Tags: time, web2py, timepicker

I have time field in my database:

`Field('start_time','time')`

which gets rendered as follows in my form:

`<input type="text" value="" name="start_time" id="mytable_start_time" class="span4 time 
hasTimeEntry" autocomplete="off">`

This creates an input box which accepts a time such as:

`12:05:39`

For my use case seconds are unnecessary how can I remove seconds so the input is:

`12:05`

Furthermore I would like to specify time in 12-hour time with am/pm rather than 24-hour time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web2py uses the jQuery Time Entry plugin -- you can learn about how to configure it [here](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html). The code for the plugin is included at the bottom of /static/js/calendar.js.

You can adjust the defaults by setting them after calendar.js has loaded. If you're using the standard layout.html, that would be right after the web2py_ajax.html include:

```
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}

<script>
jQuery.timeEntry.setDefaults({show24Hours: false, showSeconds: false});
</script>
```

Comment: I see the configuration is via javascript (e.g. `$('#showSeconds').timeEntry({showSeconds: true});`).  Where/how would I put this in my web2py code? In my view? What about globally changing it vs changing it for one specific form?

Answer (score 1):

Didnt have the ability to post a comment but in layout.html (timesteps is optional but sure is nice and easy!)

```
  {{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
<script>
    jQuery.timeEntry.setDefaults({show24Hours: false, showSeconds: false, timeSteps:            [1,30,1]});
</script>
```

And I believe if you dont want it globally just use this inside of your view instead of layout or create another layout and include that in your view instead of the default...